# Magento 2 - Saved Billing Address is not passed on COD

Tags: magento2, cash-on-delivery, place-order

When trying to place an order on the mode of COD for the already existing Address, the order is not placed throws 400 bad request issue. On reviewing the console, we found that the billing address is not passed. Refer the below screenshot.

[image]

> Default API URL:
>   https://www.domain.com/rest/english/V1/carts/mine/payment-information

But for Newly added address the orders are placing.

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue?